# How to open drop down list without shifting header jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi all i work with dropdown list with language.

This list are in header on my web page, when i tap in to language, all header height shifted.

```js
$('.language-select').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');

})

$('.language-select li').click(function () {
    $('ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
.language-select:hover {
    background-color: #242424;
    color: #fff;
}

.language-select {
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    height: 45px;
    width: 220px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    /*Animate*/
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}

    .language-select li {
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: left;
        order: 2;
        min-height: 49px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding: 10px 5px 10px 10px;
    }

        .language-select li:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            background: #191919;
        }

        .language-select li img {
            margin-right: 10px;
            width: 24px;
            height: 24px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .language-select li span {
            vertical-align: middle;
            display: inline-block;
        }

    .language-select.open {
        height: auto;
    }

    .language-select li.active {
        order: 1;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

.icon-boxes {
    background-color: #7c7c7c;
    opacity: 0.88;
    margin: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.container-fluid {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
    <div class="icon-boxes">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                        <ul class="language-select">
                            <li class="active" data-lang="ua"><img src="~/images/flas/ua.png"><span>Ukraine</span></li>
                            <li data-lang="en"><img src="~/images/flas/eng.png"><span>English</span></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So as u can see when u tap in to language,header are increase in size, but i didn't want this. How this drop list can open and did not increase size of header?

Maybe it's possible to do this collapible without touch header height.

Answer (score 0):

just try to set . it will work for you.

```
.icon-boxes {
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: So heade height must be flexible